# How to set a full length background in a Highcharts bar chart?

Tags: jquery, background, highcharts, bar-chart

I want to create a bar chart using the Highcharts plugin, where the each bar has a background color and on load it gets filled up (kind of like a loading bar). For now I only were able to do this using stacked bars and calculating a "filler" series.

*Example [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eJ4p/2/):*

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() { 
                        if(this.series.name != 'Filler')
                            return Math.round(this.percentage) + '%';
                        else return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                pointWidth: 18,
                stacking: 'percent',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            shared: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<i>' + this.points[1].x +'</i>: <b>'+ Math.round(this.points[1].percentage) +'%</b>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'background filler',
            data: [7, 9, 8, 5, 10]
        }, {
            name: 'actual Value',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }]
    });
});
```

I would love to have a fixed "bar background", so that it does not fill up on load. If possible I don't want to add a filler series and calculate its data via javascript (as I do now).

How can I accomplish it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want a static background and then your real data bar to animate over top of it.  You can do this by disabling grouping of the bars, and only animating one of the series.

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        grouping: false
    }
}
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eJ4p/4/).

Comment: Pretty close.
One small drawback: If I have small data values I would waste a lot of chart width because od 'max: 100' and a series filling up to 100.

So I assume it is NOT possible to simply set something like series.backgroundColor (I know this does not exist). Is it then possible to get a max-value (like "yAxis.max" or "data.maxValue") from a highcharts object BEFORE it got rendered, so I can use this to generate a dynamic filler series without losing too much chart width?

Comment: @Seika85, I only choose 100 because it looked like you were dealing with percents in your example.  Instead of trying to query highcharts for these maxes, it's easier to pre-screen your data; updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8eJ4p/5/

Comment: Thank you. I updated the fiddle for use with series.data of variable size/length and float values: [jsfiddle.net/8eJ4p/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/8eJ4p/6/). Although I'm not fully satisfied with this solution I will mark it as accepted answer, because it is limited by Highcharts itself.

Comment: Do you know any way on how to achieve the same effect, but having more than one data series **stacked**?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.animation.

Heres a demo for fixed column bar - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wUQrF/2/)

```
plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    animation: false
                }
            }
```

Comment: But I want my "actual Data" to be animated. Why doesn't it seem to be possible to just draw a fixed, unanimated background behind the actual data bar over the full chart width?

Comment: +1 because getting me in the right direction (did not know the animation options until now)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Kx3p8/) maybe. What I did was load the "background" series first. Then after it is displayed I add in the real data series in the `chart.events` section:

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
        load: function () {
            this.addSeries({
                name: 'actual Value',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Sorry. In your example the filler bars are flying in without filling the whole chart width and then the actual data bars are sliding in until they attach to the filler bars. Looks extremely weird...

Comment: It does. Use Mark's answer. Much more useful.